# Displaying app main menu/home screen when returning to app after having started an external Activity/Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm starting Android Market via my app to search for similar products using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://market.android.com/search?q=pub:\"some txt\""));
c.startActivity(intent);
```

This works fine for showing similar products.  However, if I hit the home button while in the market, when I re-open the app it still shows market results.  I want to go to the main menu in this case.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` is probably not the correct solution.  Note the semantics of it -- the activity just doesn't appear in the history.  Thus if the user taps on one of the things in it to go to the next activity, then pressing back, they will not return to the previous one (but the one before).  This is rarely what you want.

Worse, if they go to a second activity from the market activity, press home, and return to your app, the second activity will still be there (it is keeping itself in the history).

The correct flag for this situation is [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET).

Comment: It helped me a lot. +1 for your efforts.

Answer (score 10):

If you add the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) flag to the intent, it won't be kept on the history stack. When the user navigates back to your application, the last activity that was visible before you launched the marketplace will be shown.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("http://market.android.com/search?q=pub:\"some txt\"")); 

c.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
c.startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit:** [hackbod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453398/android-new-intent/2457028#2457028) is correct: [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET) is a better fit for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem.

When you press home on the Market app it isn't closed, just paused. So when you open it again you resume it. Check [Android activity's lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife).

Comment: Yes it is a problem since this is not the behaviour the user expects. How about you read: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET